# Does ExactTarget Provide A Callback for Subscriber Created Event

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

When a subscriber is created via the ExactTarget API, there is no problem.  But, when a subscriber is created via the Web Service User Interface, how can the web service let my API implementation know that a subscriber has been created from there?

My implementation of the ExactTarget API includes generating a hash token and assigning it to the subscriber (e.g. 7da19ca866b7ddbcb779c341a459c35b98e00c4f).  The hash token is used to search for the subscriber without showing their email address in links.  With the hash token in the link, the linked page can then use the hash token to find the user and work with their attributes, lists, etc.

My question: is there a way for ExactTarget to tell my script that a user has just been created, when the creation occurs from the Web Service UI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that there is no mechanism to do a callback, but perhaps someone more knowledgeable will chime in.  My question is do you really need real time data, or will almost real time data work?  You could set up a process on your end to query ET every 10 minutes or so, with a lookup based on CreatedTime within last 10 minutes.

Comment: I thought that a cron job would be a great idea, too.  But sometimes a list will be added from the web screen and a welcome email will be sent out immediately.  In this case, I do need a real time trigger to my API implementation.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion I can add is if you have a piece of code in your Welcome email which makes a call to your API. With that approach no matter how the subscriber is added to the list you'll get a call to you end-point.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is now available (for those searching in 2019).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createCallback.htm